# Send email to gmail with inline images and MIME::LITE

Tags: perl, gmail, email-attachments

I need to send an email to gmail with some inline images.

I use perl and MIME:LITE, but Gmail shows my image as Attachment, not inline.

What's the problem?

This is my code,

```
use MIME::Lite;

my $texto = '<html><body>hola <img src="cid:image" /> adios </body></html>';

#
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    Date            => "Xxx, 22 Oct 2012 17:45:00 CET",
    From            => "pruebachunga@aqui.com",
    To              => 'chimpun@forum.chimpun',
    Subject         => "En un lugar de la mancha",
    'Message-ID'    => '123456789012345656789@8888888888888ldkf',
    Type            =>'multipart/related'
);

$msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => $texto,
    Encoding => 'quoted-printable'
);

$msg->attach(
    Encoding => 'base64',
    Type => 'image/png',
    Path     => "image.png",
    Id => "image"
);

$msg->scrub(['x-mailer', 'Content-Disposition']);

print $msg->as_string;
```

The result is this email (I strip image secction)

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="_----------=_135100636840600"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Xxx, 22 Oct 2012 17:45:00 CET
From: pruebachunga.com
To: chimpun@forum.chimpun
Subject: En un lugar de la mancha
Message-Id: 123456789012345656789@8888888888888ldkf

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_----------=_135100636840600
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body>hola <img src=3D"cid:image" /> adios </body></html>=

--_----------=_135100636840600
Content-Id: <image>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/png; name="image.png"

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAMAAAEwO1XwAAAAB3RJTUUH1gYE
...
kmqg1wGgkx35p/KStnLuw2BGhXwIZqT+D8sxTLVK0VpuAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

--_----------=_135100636840600--
```

**EDIT**:

After reading on the web, I think that image is an attachment and has a problem known as "Image Blocking": https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/image-blocking-in-email/

I maintained my question because people may find this question interesting. Now, I think that this code is correct, and with the other message, other ID, other sender... this code can run well.

Comment: What happens if you change the content ID for the image to have a .png extension? So you reference it as `"cid:image.png"` in the HTML and set the `Id` param to `image.png` when you attach it.

Comment: Yes, I try it... same result. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading on the web, I think that image is an attachment and has a problem known as "Image Blocking": https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/image-blocking-in-email/

I maintained my question because people may find this question interesting. Now, I think that this code is correct, and with the other message, other ID, other sender... this code can run well.

Answer (score 1):

You should not scrub 'Content-Disposition' field - it is important!

MIME::Lite is using inline content disposition by default,
but you can also set it explicitly

```
$msg->attach(
    Encoding => 'base64',
    Type     => 'image/png',
    Path     => 'image.png',
    Id       => 'image',
    Disposition => 'inline',
);
```

and it should all work.

Answer (score -1):

I use **exter**nal variant.

```
my $mailHTML = new MIME::Lite::HTML
    From    => $i_from,
    To      => $i_to,
    Subject => $i_subj,
    IncludeType => 'extern',
    HTMLCharset => 'utf-8';
```

In this case, you need specify in HTML like

```
<img src="http://external_url/to_image">
```

http or https!